# Open window popup from HyperLink in c# not working in IE 11

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink, internet-explorer-11

I have added this `HyperLink` in markup aspx page for open `window popup` from `GridView`.

This code working correctly on `Google Chrome` but is open new webpage on `Internet Explorer 11` and not window popup.

In the folder of project I have added the subfolder `App_Browsers` without success.

How to do resolve this ?

Can you help me?

Thank you in advance, my code below.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="btest">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btest" Text="btest"

        NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("btest.aspx?sID={0}", Eval("Sample_ID"))%>' 
        onclick="javascript:w= window.open(this.href,'Sample_ID',
       'left=20,top=20,width=1500,height=300,toolbar=0,resizable=0');return false;">

       </asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: IE settings define what happens with popup windows (popup/new tab/new window). I'm afraid there is no way to code around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a page in new window depends on your browser settings.
window.open will have different behaviour in different browser as per browser settings.

if you want to make same behaviour in all browser, use any modal popup like jquery modal or bootstrap modal.

Please find links below.

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals